# NextJS - SEO SSR Pages and _NEXT_DATA

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a website that has SSR pages. Now when we view source an SSR Page; it has the _NEXT_DATA JSON.

SEO articles say that they ideally want HTML for crawling as opposed to DATA (JSON). So how does NextJS do a great job with SEO ? Want to know the internals and objective of what extra thing NextJS SSR does to ensure a good SEO ranking ?

Also the below article says :
The most important thing for SEO is that page data and metadata is available on page load without JavaScript. In this case SSG or SSR are going to be your best options.

https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/rendering-and-ranking/rendering-strategies

What do they mean by page data ? Can we call _NEXT_DATA = page data ? Or they mean HTML when they refer page data ?

I want to know how does a crawler rank a NextJS SSR page ?

Answer (score 2):

SSR works like this:
Client makes a request to the website -> NextJS fetches data and renders the HTML -> pre-rendered HTML is being served to the client

So the client gets a pre-rendered page and does not have to fetch the data himself. When viewing the source, you can see the pre-rendered HTML page. When crawlers visit your page, they do not need to execute any javascript, but instead can use the pre-rendered page.